# How to make Violin Plots from a text file

Tags: r, ggplot2

Currently, I am trying to make an image of multiple violin graphs that I read in from a text file. The text file is formatted in a way so that there a "count" column which is just incrementing by 1 to show the index of the results, and there are also multiple columns each being the results of a different variable size. Below is an example of a portion of the text file.

```
Count  X1.1     X1.2     X1.3     X1.4     
1      174.647  173.368  172.713  172.264 
2      169.549  166.791  167.010  165.682 
3      174.341  170.821  169.861  169.103 
4      178.305  177.736  177.796  176.067 
5      160.614  159.842  158.548  157.145
```

So I would like to create a new violin graph for each column using ggplot (1.1, 1.2, etc.) that can be displayed side by side.

```
library(ggplot2)
myData <- read.csv("E2_1_RingSize.text", sep = "\t", header=TRUE)
```

I've read in the file I would want, and am able to plot one column at a time by hard coding in the column name. See below

```
graph1 <- ggplot(myData, aes(x=Count, y=X1.1) + geom_violin()
```

But I'm unsure how to include all of the columns at once. It's most likely an easy fix, only 1-2 lines, but I'm not that experienced in R/RStudio and so I've got no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is pivot your data.frame so it's in long format:

```
dat %>% 
    tidyr::pivot_longer(-Count) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(name), y=value)) + geom_violin()
```

Comment: Hi user438383, thanks for the quick reply. I'm just a little confused as to the implementation of this, I pasted this into my code and called library(magrittr), but this code resulted in an error for me. Is there something more I have to do to implement it. At the moment it results in (Error in tidyr::pivot_longer(., Count) : object 'dat' not found)

Comment: @William change the dat to whatever you have your data.frame saved as - I think you called it myData